# Consult the previous date closest to the query

Tags: oracle

Table records:

```
process date total
------------ -----
31/12/2018     433  
30/09/2018     433  
09/07/2018    1873
```

When consulting the date : `09/07/2018`
the result is:

```
process date total
------------ -----
09/07/2018    1873
```

When consulting the date: `30/09/2018`
the result is:

```
process date total
------------ -----
30/09/2018     433
```

When consulting the date: `10/08/2018`
the result is:

```
process date total  
------------ -----
09/07/2018    1873
```

what it should bring is:

```
process date total  
------------ -----
30/09/2018     433
```

the correct result should be `09/07/2018`

full consultation: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fd6399037808abb01ff33f8ccb6523e).

```
SELECT 'POR SECTOR ECONOMICO' AS VCH_RUBRO,
   UPPER(CHR_SECECO) AS VCH_CODGRUPO,
   UPPER(VC_SECECO) AS VCH_DESGRUPO,
   SUM(INT_NROPRESTAMO) AS INT_NROPRESTAMO,
   SUM(INTO_BENEFICIARIOS) AS INTO_BENEFICIARIOS,
   SUM(DEC_SALCON) AS DEC_SALCON
FROM (      
 SELECT              
     CHR_SECECO,
     VC_SECECO,
     COUNT(*) AS INT_NROPRESTAMO,       
     0 AS INTO_BENEFICIARIOS,
     SUM(DEC_SALCON) AS DEC_SALCON             
FROM (
     SELECT 
        INT_IDPRESTAMODET, 
        DTE_FECPRO,
        CHR_SECECO,
        VC_SECECO,
        DEC_SALCON,                
        RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY DIFERENCIA ) AS ROWNUMBER
     FROM (
            SELECT 
                PREDET.INT_IDPRESTAMODET, 
                PREDET.DTE_FECPRO,
                (PREDET.DEC_IMPSAL) AS DEC_SALCON,
                ABS(PREDET.DTE_FECPRO - TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY')) AS DIFERENCIA,
                AGRUP.VC_CODDET AS CHR_SECECO,
                AGRUP.VC_NOMDET AS VC_SECECO
            FROM TB_JSI_PRESTAMO_DETALLE PREDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_PRESTAMO PRE ON PRE.INT_IDPRESTAMO=PREDET.INT_IDPRESTAMO
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_BENEFICIARIO_IFI BENIFI ON BENIFI.INT_IDBENEIFI=PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI                    
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_OPERACION OPE ON PRE.INT_IDOPE = OPE.INT_IDOPE AND OPE.DT_FECVEN>TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY')
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_CIIU CIIU ON PRE.INT_IDACT = CIIU.INT_IDACT AND PRE.INT_IDSEC=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS --26
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET SECECO ON SECECO.INT_IDDET=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_AGRUPA_SECTOR AGRSEC ON SECECO.INT_IDDET = AGRSEC.INT_IDSEC 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET AGRUP ON AGRSEC.INT_IDAGRU = AGRUP.INT_IDDET 
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET MON ON OPE.INT_IDMON = MON.INT_IDDET
            WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDTIPPRO = 2) 
                  AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDMON = 364)
                  AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDIFI=72)
                  AND PREDET.DEC_SALDOL>0
          )                  
        )
    WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1 GROUP BY CHR_SECECO,VC_SECECO
UNION ALL

SELECT 
         CHR_SECECO,
         VC_SECECO,
         0 AS INT_NROPRESTAMO,  
         COUNT(*) AS INTO_BENEFICIARIOS,
         0 AS DEC_SALCON 
      FROM (
          SELECT 
              DISTINCT INT_IDBENEIFI,
              DTE_FECPRO,                      
              CHR_SECECO,
              VC_SECECO,
              RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY DIFERENCIA ) AS ROWNUMBER
          FROM (
              SELECT 
                  ABS(PREDET.DTE_FECPRO - TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY')) AS DIFERENCIA,
                  PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI,
                  PREDET.DTE_FECPRO,
                  AGRUP.VC_CODDET AS CHR_SECECO,
                  AGRUP.VC_NOMDET AS VC_SECECO
FROM TB_JSI_PRESTAMO_DETALLE PREDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_PRESTAMO PRE ON PRE.INT_IDPRESTAMO=PREDET.INT_IDPRESTAMO
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_BENEFICIARIO_IFI BENIFI ON BENIFI.INT_IDBENEIFI=PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_CIIU CIIU ON PRE.INT_IDACT = CIIU.INT_IDACT AND PRE.INT_IDSEC=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET SECECO ON CIIU.INT_IDCLAS = SECECO.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_AGRUPA_SECTOR AGRSEC ON SECECO.INT_IDDET = AGRSEC.INT_IDSEC
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET AGRUP ON AGRSEC.INT_IDAGRU = AGRUP.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_OPERACION OPE ON PRE.INT_IDOPE = OPE.INT_IDOPE AND OPE.DT_FECVEN>TRUNC(TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY'))
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET MON ON OPE.INT_IDMON = MON.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_IFI IFI ON OPE.INT_IDIFI = IFI.INT_IDIFI 
                  WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDTIPPRO = 2) 
                          AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDMON = 364)
                          AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDIFI=72)
                          AND PREDET.DEC_SALDOL>0
                  )                  
                )
                WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1 GROUP BY CHR_SECECO,VC_SECECO
               ) PREST
 GROUP BY CHR_SECECO, VC_SECECO
 ORDER BY DEC_SALCON DESC, VC_SECECO;
```

Comment: This seems to be identical to your [previous (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56463850/266304), and you haven't addressed the comments on that. Your fiddle doesn't add anything as there are no tables or data, you haven't simplified the query, and as Thorsten Kettner pointed out, 2018-07-09 *is* closer to 2018-08-10 than 2018-09-30 (32 days vs. 51 days) - so why do you want 2018-09-30?

Comment: The query must be to the previous date closest to the one consulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `ABS` then dates in the future will be positive; so I think you can then just filter them out:

```
...
              RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY DIFERENCIA ) AS ROWNUMBER
          FROM (
              SELECT 
                  -- remove the ABS() call
                  -- ABS(PREDET.DTE_FECPRO - TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY')) AS DIFERENCIA,
                  PREDET.DTE_FECPRO - TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY') AS DIFERENCIA,
                  PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI,
                  PREDET.DTE_FECPRO,
                  AGRUP.VC_CODDET AS CHR_SECECO,
                  AGRUP.VC_NOMDET AS VC_SECECO
FROM TB_JSI_PRESTAMO_DETALLE PREDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_PRESTAMO PRE ON PRE.INT_IDPRESTAMO=PREDET.INT_IDPRESTAMO
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_BENEFICIARIO_IFI BENIFI ON BENIFI.INT_IDBENEIFI=PRE.INT_IDBENEIFI
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_CIIU CIIU ON PRE.INT_IDACT = CIIU.INT_IDACT AND PRE.INT_IDSEC=CIIU.INT_IDCLAS
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET SECECO ON CIIU.INT_IDCLAS = SECECO.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_AGRUPA_SECTOR AGRSEC ON SECECO.INT_IDDET = AGRSEC.INT_IDSEC
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET AGRUP ON AGRSEC.INT_IDAGRU = AGRUP.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_OPERACION OPE ON PRE.INT_IDOPE = OPE.INT_IDOPE AND OPE.DT_FECVEN>TRUNC(TO_DATE('30/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YY'))
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_TABLA_DET MON ON OPE.INT_IDMON = MON.INT_IDDET
INNER JOIN TB_JSI_IFI IFI ON OPE.INT_IDIFI = IFI.INT_IDIFI 
                  WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDTIPPRO = 2) 
                          AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDMON = 364)
                          AND (NULL IS NULL OR OPE.INT_IDIFI=72)
                          AND PREDET.DEC_SALDOL>0
                  )                  
                  -- add a filter
                  WHERE DIFERENCIA <= 0
                )
                WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1 GROUP BY CHR_SECECO,VC_SECECO
...
```

I've kept your original formatting; it would be easier to see what is going on if you indented properly. I've included comments for the two changes. Obviously I don't have your tables or data so untested...